# JsonPath create from path on the fly

Tags: java, jsonpath

I'm using https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath, I want to set fields that might not be yet set in the document. For example: `doc.set(JsonPath.compile("$.some.array[0].value"), "abc");` on an `{}` document would result in:

```
{
  "some": {
    "array": [
      {
        "value": "abc"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I was thinking of trying to using the the compiled path, and get access to the path tokens to work my way through the document, but it doesn't seem that they are accessible. Is there any good way or alternative way of doing this?

Being able to access the path tokens in order to create fields that are needed